# Informix datetime with prepared statement

Tags: sql, datetime, informix

I am doing this:

```
Select count(*) from table1 t where start_datetime = datetime(?);
```

Setting datetime using:

```
ps.setString("01-01-2010 12:12:00.123")
```

It is giving error as : Non numeric character in datetime or interval.

But if I run this as SQL in SQL Editor it works all fine.

Any clues how to correct this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change around the string to conform to the default `datetime` date pattern

```
ps.setString("2010-01-01 12:12:00.1230")
```

I think something like this should also work

```
select count(*) from table1 t 
               where start_datetime = TO_DATE(?,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %F3")
```

Let me know